# I am in need of a method of storing many different items in a list

Tags: java, arrays, list, object, hash

I have a program written in java that desperately needs to be optimized. Right now i have 3 ArrayLists that i would like to be simplified into 1 list type thing. I have one ArrayList for rectangles, one for booleans, and one for an object that i have created with one of my classes. We can call it "Item" for now. I keep the three ArrayLists in the same order, by doing the same thing to all of them. For example, every time i create a new Item, i add it to the item ArrayList, i add a boolean to that ArrayList and i add a rectangle to the third ArrayList. 
   I am looking for a solution. I tried HashMaps, but they only take 2 pieces of information per list item. At one point i tried an ArrayList but it was a huge pain to deal with. If anyone could help me find a solution, i would be hugely appreciative. Thanks so much.

EDIT: Thanks for all the quick answers

Comment: Is creating a composite object, that contains item, rectangle and boolean not an option

Comment: why does it needs to be optimized, where is the problem, does it take time to retrieve data or store it?

Comment: The code is longer, messier and becomes annoying to write.

Answer (score 10):

Write a new class that has your "rectangle", boolean and "item" as fields and store instances of that class in a single List.

For example:

```
public class MyRecord {
    private Rectange rectangle;
    private boolean flag;
    private Item item;

    // getters / setters
}
```

Then in your other class (wherever you have your lists):

```
...
List<MyRecord> list = ...; // initialize or obtain from somewhere
list.get(0).setFlag(false); // modify field within your container object
```

Comment: So simple yet for some reason i hadnt thought of that. For curiosity sake, is there a built in method for handling things like this?

Comment: @Joe there's nothing "built-in" really - mostly because it's trivial to create a container class like above. Well, you can in theory do a List of Map instances, but both performance- and readability- wise that's far from ideal solution

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you store your three associated items in a class, and then make a list of them?

```
class MyThingy {
    public MyItem item;
    public boolean flag;
    public Rectangle rect;
}

List<MyThingy> myList = new ArrayList<MyThingy>();
```

Adapt `public`/`private` and getters/setters as required.

Answer (score 2):

The only things that comes immediately to my mind is to do an object that has reference to the boolean, the rectangle and your other object.

Answer (score 1):

You need a data class, which has the three objects as fields, and make a list of the data objects.
Something like this:

```
public class ItemData {
    private final Item item;
    private final boolean flag;
    private final Rectangle rectangle;
    private ItemData(Item item, boolean flag, Rectangle rectangle) {
        this.item = item;
        this.flag = flag;
        this.rectangle = rectangle;
    }
    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }
    public boolean isFlag() {
        return flag;
    }
    public Rectangle getRectangle() {
        return rectangle;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<ItemData> list = new ArrayList<ItemData>();
}
```

Oh... maybe they give prizes for coming 2nd, 3rd etc :)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without some more background information such as what the relationship between the items in your list is, but I'm guessing you could either do it the easy way if it seems appropriate to do so:

Creating an object that has the rectangle and the boolean as instance variables.

If you don't feel like this would be appropriate, you could nest a Hashtable inside another hashtable, but I wouldn't necessarily recommend that as it adds unnecessary complexity to your program.

Comment: Ok Thanks. IT seems like java would have something like that but i guess there is no reason that they should.